# Filtering and display unique column pairs in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Follow on from [Excel Count unique value multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456189/excel-count-unique-value-multiple-columns)

I am trying to filter and setup a table containing all the unique combinations of message types.

So with three message types as an example below, I want to create a table with all the possible flows from this.

So every time MessageA exists, it is either followed by a MessageA, MessageB, MessageC or is the last of the sequence.
And everytime we see MessageC it is only followed by MessageA.

*On the left, is the data and on the right is the desired result.*

[image: Sample Data]

I want this to be able to scale to multiple columns/rows

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, can you explain how you got to the numbers in desired result?

Comment: I can understand why A-> A = 2 and A-> B = 3, but why A-> C = 2 and A-> END = 5 I can't. By the logic of the example, it turns out that A-> A is looking at 1-> 1 column, A-> B is also looking at 1-> 1 column, A-> C is looking at 2-> 3 columns, and A-> END is looking at 1->4 column

Comment: @Basic So the reason why we have  A-> A = 2 (2nd and 3rd row have MessageA followed by MessageA, column A->B)
And  A-> B = 3 (1st,2nd,3rd row has MessageA -> MessageB column A->B)

Comment: It would be to generate all the unique value pairs from Column A ->B, B->C, C -> D, D -> E

Comment: @Zac, Iv tried pivot table , but can only do for two rows at a time, but isn't really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by comparing two offset ranges, A1:D5 and B1:E5

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$D$5=$G2)*($B$1:$E$5=K$1))
```

[image]

As you can see, I have cheated slightly by setting K1 blank so it compares correctly with column E, but this could be made part of a longer formula if it was necessary to have END as the column header for K.